# Is the Linksys WRT54GL a Linux router?

Tags: linux, router

I heard that Linux routers can be programmed. I had re-programmed by Linksys WRT54GL router using ddwrt. So is it a Linux router?

Comment: They can't be reprogrammed to the same degree, nor as easily, as say a full computer running Linux using two network ports to route and/or firewall traffic, but yeah, DD-WRT is Linux-based running a 2.4 kernel IIRC, at least that's what my WRT-54GS is running...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the clue is in the 'L' at the end!

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linksys_WRT54G_series#WRT54GL

Answer (score 4):

Whether a stock WRT54GL runs Linux (it does) doesn't have much to do with what you want to do, which is reprogram it. You put (Linux based) ddwrt on it, so it is definitely now a Linux router.

It just depends on whether someone do the work to make Linux run on it.  For example, you can take an old iPod, which does not run Linux, and then convert it to run Linux.  You can also do this with a PS/3.